# 302 status is getting when submit form in laravel 5.5. After submit the form page is redirecting back

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a form and inputs are inside loop. Each inputs are validating using [Laravel validation array method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays). At present I am submitted name as `name="guest[{{ $cart->_id }}][sleeps]"` and `name="guest[{{ $cart->_id }}][comments]"`. Validation is working fine for each input. But data is not submitted in to controller page. After submit page is redirect back. I am getting `http 302 status`. I have attached chrome console result. How can we submit data in to controller when I submit the form?

If I change name like `name="sleeps[]"` and `name="comments[]"` the data is posting in to controller. Any help would be appreciated.

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/cart/store', 'CartController@store')->name('cart.store');
```

**Html**

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.store') }}" method="post">

 {{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="panel panel-default text-left panel-booking1 panel-default-booking1">
    @forelse($carts as $key => $cart)
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4-booking1 form-group {{ $errors->has('guest.*.sleeps') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label>Sleep(s)</label>

        <select class="form-control form-control-booking1 jsBookCalSleep"  name="guest[{{ $cart->_id }}][sleeps]">
        <option value="">Choose Sleep(s)</option>
        @for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++)
           <option value="{{ $i }}" @if($i == $cart->sleeps) selected @endif>{{ $i }}</option>
        @endfor
        </select>

        @if ($errors->has('guest.*.sleeps'))
             <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('guest.*.sleeps') }}</strong></span>
        @endif
    </div> 

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4-f-booking1 comment-booking1 col-sm-4-booking1">
       <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has($inputComments) ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
         <textarea id="comments_{{ $cart->_id }}" name="guest[{{ $cart->_id }}][comments]" class="form-control" rows="3" maxlength="300" placeholder="Comment...">{{ old($inputComments) }}</textarea>

         @if ($errors->has($inputComments))
           <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first($inputComments) }}</strong></span>
         @endif

      </div>
    </div> 

    @empty
      <p>No bookings in your cart</p>
    @endforelse

<div>
<div id="btn-ground-2-booking1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default-booking1 btn-default btn-sm btn-details btn-details-booking1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card" style="font-size: 14px;" aria-hidden="true"></span> Payment</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**CartRequest.php**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'guest.*.sleeps'     => 'required|not_in:0',
            'guest.*.comments'   => 'max:300',
        ];
    }
```

**CartController.php**

```
public function store(CartRequest $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

[image]

Comment: 302 is a redirect code not error.

Comment: Can you check what is the result of name="guest[{{ $cart->_id }}][comments] in inspect element?

Comment: @Nirali The result is `guest[5ac5e2e09a892042bb7b2d59][comments]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'guest' => 'array'
    ];
    foreach($this->request->get('guest') as $key => $val){
        $rules['guest.'.$key.'. sleeps'] = 'required|not_in:0';
        $rules['guest.'.$key.'. comments'] = 'max:300';
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me partially. If I remove the first rule ($rules['guest.'.$key.'. sleeps'] = 'required|not_in:0';) the data is post in to controller. Here is the result  array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "N7J9k5KMbv3WvU0OuKR6ZmDjm1D1udbemKKA5RLJ"
  "guest" => array:2 [▼
    "5acb27dd9a892042bb7b2d5c" => array:4 [▼
      "beds" => "2"
      "dormitory" => null
      "sleeping_place" => "0"
      "comments" => "test"
    ]
    "5acb280a9a89205a311248f3" => array:3 [▼
      "sleeps" => "1"
      "sleeping_place" => "1"
      "comments" => "tested"
    ]
  ]
]

Comment: Issue is because of space b/w rules `'guest.'.$key.'. sleeps'`. Now it's working fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

302 is redirection code.do something like this

```
Route::post('/cart/store', 'CartController@store')->name('cart.store'); 
Replace the form tag by below line and check it.

<?php echo Form::open(['url' => '/cart/store', 'method' => 'post']); ?>
```

Comment: I am not submitting form using ajax method.

Comment: I have added chrome console result in my question